# LoadError for rails 2 script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I manage a server running an old rails 2 app (being upgraded to rails 4 soon) and there's a script giving an error that running the same code from the console does not.  It outputs this when I run the script:

```
rails@net:/c$ RAILS_ENV=production script/runner stc_cron.rb 
/current/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/runner.rb:45: /current/vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/../../activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_missing_constant': Expected /current/vendor/other_extensions/stc/app/models/contact.rb to define Contact (LoadError)
```

but the exact same code run in the rails console is fine and /current/vendor/other_extensions/stc/app/models/contact.rb does define Contact and has no errors

here's the code from the script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = ARGV[0] || 'production'
require 'config/boot'
Extension.load_all
require 'lib/satacard'
stc=SaTaCard.new
stc.get_and_process_new_stc
stc.get_and_process_new_contacts
```

why would it run fine in the console but fail in the script?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not loading the Rails environment. Load it after config/boot:

```
require 'config/environment'
```

Comment: I tried this and get the same error...it also ignores the first line setting RAILS_ENV to 'production' for some reason...I am able to get it to run correctly if I create a rake task that loads our extensions and includes the last four lines as the task and then run it with rake